# Software that records the sent and received usage of a connection in Windows Network Connections and allow limits

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitor

Under Windows Control Panel, Network and Internet, Network Connections options, there are a list of connections. When double-click on any of the connection, a Status window will pop up displaying the activity of sent and received in bytes.

Is there a gratis windows (or cross-platform java) software (support Windows XP and above) that logs the activity of each connection and allow user to view past activity records, filter by days or weeks or month. And also allows user to set a limit (e.g. A limit of 200 MB for X days or 1 month, when the activity exceed that limit, it will not allow any network traffic)

Comment: Won't allow limits (not in the free version anyways,  not sure about the paid version) but a great network monitoring tool/firewall: https://www.glasswire.com